# how do i get the specific array index based on value inside the index's object? flex

Tags: arrays, flash, apache-flex, object, actionscript

So, for sending to individual streams we have to reference the connected netStream we want to send to in some way like this:

```
sendStream.peerStreams[0].send("MyFunction",param1,param2);
```

and I have to determine which peer I'm sending to by their ID such as "peerID1234"

I know that you can check the peerID of the stream by doing:

```
sendStream.peerStreams[0]["farID"]
```

how can I make my send stream function know to use the array index where the peerID is?

so basically it could be like:

```
sendStream.peerStreams[where peerStreams[]["farID"] == peerID].send("MyFunction",param1,param2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you'll have to loop through the `peerStreams` array to find the object that has the right `farID` property value. Basically you are searching through the array for an item with a specific property value. There is no built-in functionality for this. But you can do it with a simple loop. Something like this:

```
var correctStream:Object = null;
for each (var stream:Object in sendStream.peerStreams) {
   if (stream["farId"] == peerId) {
     correctStream = stream;
     break;
   }
}
correctStream.send("MyFunction",param1,param2);
```

Note that I don't know what the data type is for the `peerStreams` object so I just typed it as `Object` in my example.

There's some other approaches mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933257/as3-is-it-possible-to-search-an-array-by-object-properties) but they are just different styles of doing the same thing.

Comment: ah i was thinking Id have to actually get the index number for some reason. But with this I can just use the send function right on the correctStream var. so this works, thanks a lot!